# Using loops to find matching words between lists

Tags: r, loops

I have two datasets. One is a list of 72 items, where each item is a list itself that consists of 10 sentences. Therefore, I have a total of 720 sentences, each separated by lists of 10.

The second set of data is a list of all the words in the first dataset that end in "ing".

I want to see for each list item, if an "ing" word is contained in any of the ten sentences of said list.

If so, what ing words are present in the list and is this the first time the word appears in the dataset overall (i.e., first time it shows up across all 720 sentences)? I then plan to compile all that information into a table

This is what I have so far. I just wanted to see if it would print what lists each ing word was found in, before moving onto the more complicated parts.

```
n <- 1

harvardList[1]
for(word in IngWords){
  if(IngWords==harvardList[n])
  print(harvardList[n])
  n <- n+1
}
```

When I run that script I get these errors and output:

```
Error: unexpected 'in' in:
"for(word in IngWords){
  if(word in"
 print(harvardList[n])
$`List 1`
$`List 1`[[1]]
[1] "The birch canoe slid on the smooth planks."

etc., 

>   n <- n+1
> }
Error: unexpected '}' in "}"
```

This is a mini version of the sentence list:

```
$`List 1`[[1]]
[1] "The source of the huge river is the clear spring."

$`List 1`[[2]]
[1] "Help the woman get back to her feet."

$`List 1`[[3]]
[1] "A pot of tea helps to pass the evening."

$`List 2`[[1]]
[1] "The colt reared and threw the tall rider."

$`List 2`[[2]]
[1] "It snowed, rained, and hailed the same morning."

$`List 2`[[3]]
[1] "Read verse out loud for pleasure."

$`List 3`[[1]]
[1] "Take the winding path to reach the lake."

$`List 3`[[2]]
[1] "The meal was cooked before the bell rang."

$`List 3`[[3]]
[1] "What joy there is in living."
```

These are the ing words:

living winding morning evening spring

Expected output:

```
[List Number] [ing-word]
1             spring, evening
2             morning
3             winding, living
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We can loop over each element in list using `lapply`, split every word on space, remove the punctuations and find the words which are present in `IngWords`.

```
stack(lapply(harvardList, function(x) {
   all_words <- gsub("[[:punct:]]", "", unlist(strsplit(unlist(x), " ")))
   toString(all_words[all_words %in% IngWords])
}))[2:1]


#    ind          values
#1 List1 spring, evening
#2 List2         morning
#3 List3 winding, living
```

**data**

```
harvardList <- list(List1= list("The source of the huge river is the clear spring.",
              "Help the woman get back to her feet.", 
              "A pot of tea helps to pass the evening."), 
 List2 = list("The colt reared and threw the tall rider.", 
              "It snowed, rained, and hailed the same morning.", 
              "Read verse out loud for pleasure."), 
 List3 = list( "Take the winding path to reach the lake.", 
               "The meal was cooked before the bell rang.", 
               "What joy there is in living."))
IngWords <- c("living", "winding", "morning", "evening", "spring")
```

Answer (score 1):

We can use `tidyverse` to do this

```
library(stringr)
library(tibble)
library(purrr)
enframe(harvardList) %>% 
     unnest(c(value)) %>% 
     unnest(value) %>% 
     group_by(name) %>%
     summarise(value = toString(na.omit(str_extract(value, 
         str_c(IngWords, collapse="|")))))
# A tibble: 3 x 2
#  name  value          
#  <chr> <chr>          
#1 List1 spring, evening
#2 List2 morning        
#3 List3 winding, living
```

---

Or using `base R`

```
aggregate(values ~ ind, stack(harvardList), 
  FUN = function(x) regmatches(x, regexpr(paste(IngWords, collapse="|"), x)))
#  ind          values
#1 List1 spring, evening
#2 List2         morning
#3 List3 winding, living
```

#### data

```
harvardList <- list(List1= list("The source of the huge river is the clear spring.",
              "Help the woman get back to her feet.", 
              "A pot of tea helps to pass the evening."), 
 List2 = list("The colt reared and threw the tall rider.", 
              "It snowed, rained, and hailed the same morning.", 
              "Read verse out loud for pleasure."), 
 List3 = list( "Take the winding path to reach the lake.", 
               "The meal was cooked before the bell rang.", 
               "What joy there is in living."))
IngWords <- c("living", "winding", "morning", "evening", "spring")
```